# How to force a redraw of the JointJS canvas?

Tags: javascript, jointjs

How does one force a set of linkages to render in JointJS?

We are finding that drawing the linkages between nodes is taking too long. We would like to show our users progress of the linkages even if it slows the overall length down. We are using the Javascript library JointJS at jointjs.com and have tried multiple Javascript methods for forcing redraw of the DOM but nothing seems to be triggering a redraw.

Here are examples of code we have tried to trigger a redraw of even a portion of the DOM let alone the JointJS canvas:

```
// Fails
// var logger = document.getElementById('log');
// logger.innerHTML = "Processing..."; //  + node_name;
// logger.offsetHeight;

// Fails
//$('#logger').redraw();

// Fails
// $("#logger").hide().html(node_name).fadeIn('fast');

// Fails
// document.getElementById('log').style.display = 'none';
// document.getElementById('log').style.display = 'block';
```

Any ideas what might work?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by linkages. Are you talking about links between nodes?

Comment: @VinayPrabhakaran Yes - we would like to draw links between nodes and have them show up on the canvas one at a time. Currently, the canvas waits until our entire JSON file is parsed and all the drawing calls are made before it then suddenly draws all the links at one time.

Comment: please paste your code of where you are adding links are you adding all links on graph.addCells call at the end of the code. Please paste your code

Answer (score 1):

You can just use backbone's `view.render()`.

For example, to do an arbitrary link:

```
let link = graph.getLinks()[0];
let view = paper.findViewByModel(link.id).render();
```